# Error while registering a new user on Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I try to register a new user, I get an error saying value of type `'FIRDatabaseReference' has no member 'createuser'`. See image below.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(<email: String>, password: <String>, completion: <FIRAuthResultCallback?(FIRUser?, NSError?) -> Void#>)
```

Here is a screenshot of how the code looks like picture of the code and the imageview:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it is working absolutely fine for me

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  FirebaseExample
//
//  Created by Belal Khan on 03/10/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Belal Khan. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

//importing firebase
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //Textfields for email and password
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldPassword: UITextField!

    //label for displaying message
    @IBOutlet weak var labelMessage: UILabel!

    //button for registration
    @IBAction func buttonRegister(sender: UIButton) {
        //do the registration operation here

        //first take the email and password from the views
        let email = textFieldEmail.text
        let password = textFieldPassword.text

        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email!, password: password!, completion: { (user: FIRUser?, error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.labelMessage.text = "You are successfully registered"
            }else{
                self.labelMessage.text = "Registration Failed.. Please Try Again"
            }

        })
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //initialising firebase
        FIRApp.configure()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Source: [**swift firebase tutorial**](https://www.simplifiedios.net/firebase-ios-tutorial-user-registration/)

Answer (score 0):

The code does not match. ref.createUser is different from FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail

Answer (score 0):

This is a working piece of code I tried a few days ago in XCode 7.3.1 I am not sure which version of XCode you are using. However, there's no pre-defined function as you tried!

```
func buttonHandleRegister() {
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, password = passwordTextField.text, name = nameTextField.text else {
        print("Form is not valid")
        return
    }
    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email, password: password, completion: { (user: FIRUser?, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error")
            return
        }

        guard let uid = user?.uid else {
            return
        }

         //successfully logged in


        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL("https://some-random-name.firebaseio.com/")
        let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(uid)

        let values = ["name" : name, "email": email, "password": password]
        usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref)
            in

            if err != nil {
                print(err)
                return
            }

            print("Saved user succesfully")


        })


})
}
```